# How bind a list of ViewModel to a custom control?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm using Prism to develop a Xamarin.Form app. I'm creating a custom carousel control:

```
public class CarouselLayout : ScrollView
{
    public IList ItemsSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
           nameof(ItemsSource),
           typeof(IList),
           typeof(CarouselLayout),
           null,
           propertyChanged: (bindableObject, oldValue, newValue) =>
           {
               ((CarouselLayout)bindableObject).ItemsSourceChanged();
           }
        );

    void ItemsSourceChanged()
    {
        _stack.Children.Clear();
        foreach (var item in ItemsSource) // ItemSource is a list of ViewModels
        {
            var view = ?; // How to resolve the View for this ViewModel?
            var bindableObject = view as BindableObject;
            if (bindableObject != null)
                bindableObject.BindingContext = item; // Is this the Prism way to do this?
            _stack.Children.Add(view);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the ViewModel of ContentPage

```
public class MainPageViewModel: BindableBase
{
    private List<BaseViewModel> _viewModels;
    public List<BaseViewModel> ViewModels
    {
        get { return _viewModels; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _viewModels, value);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }

    }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        ViewModels = CreateViewModelsList();
    }

    private List<BaseViewModel> CreateViewModelsList()
    {
        return new List<BaseViewModel>{
            new FirstViewModel(),
            new SecondViewModel()
        };
    }
}
```

This is how I create the carousel in my MainPage and binding the ViewModels list:

```
var carousel = new CarouselLayout();
[...]
carousel.SetBinding(CarouselLayout.ItemsSourceProperty, "ViewModels");
```

How I bind the ViewModel to it's View in the CarouselLayout's method `ItemsSourceChanged()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Create also a bindable property for your custom control to access the `ItemTemplate` property of your control.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ItemTemplateProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemTemplate), typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(CarouselLayout ), default(DataTemplate));

public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
{
    get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
}
```

Then you will be able to do something like this:

```
foreach (var item in this.ItemsSource)
{
    var viewCell = this.ItemTemplate.CreateContent() as ViewCell;
    viewCell.View.BindingContext = item;
    _stack.Children.Add(viewCell.View);
}
```